# Convertir un .pdf a .docx usando soffice.exe - Opcion: --convert-to html no se ejecuta

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito convertir un archivo .pdf a .docx, después de investigar un poco descubrí que se puede usar libreoffice con el modulo `subprocess` para realizar la conversion, pero es necesario convertir el archivo .pdf a .html y posteriormente a .docx

usando estos comandos:

`soffice --convert-to html ./my_pdf_file.pdf    #convertir pdf a html`
`soffice --convert-to docx:'MS Word 2007 XML' ./my_pdf_file.html  #convertir html a docx`

El problema que tengo es que al tratar de ejecutar el primer comando no funciona y me sale la ventana de ayuda de comandos de open office

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estoy ejecutando mal?

este es el código:

```
import subprocess
loffice = 'C:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice.exe'
subprocess.run('"{}" --conver-to "html:XHTML Writer File:UTF8" --outdir "{}" "{}"'.format(loffice,'C:/Users/Angel-Dell/Desktop','C:/Users/Angel-Dell/Desktop/test.pdf',),shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en su momento lidie y mucho con subprocces y libreofficce, espero que esta linea te ayude:

```
crea_xlt = subprocess.Popen(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'xlt:MS Excel 97 Vorlage/Template', '--outdir', archivo_destino, archivo_origen])
```

como puedes ver cada elemento de la linea va en una lista, ignoro porque no me funcionaba por mas que escribía la linea completa pero lo que te he puesto funciona

Comment: Note que no puedo convertir archivos .pdf que tienen imagenes incluidas a .docx sabes de algun metodo he estado investigando pero no llego a nada